# Which DNA would sperms contain from a transplanted scrotum?

Tags: human-biology

We had a discussion at the coffee break today about transplanting a scrotum.

Let's assume that it's possible.

Would the produced sperms contain the DNA of the donor or the one that got the scrotum transplanted? Can you explain why?

Comment: What do you mean by pouch? Testicles? Penis? Marsupial pouch?

Comment: Found the correct word (I think). English is not my native language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is DNA replaced after organ donation?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42510/is-dna-replaced-after-organ-donation)

Comment: Johnny: I'm not asking about the organ that was donated, but the sperms produced in it. Aren't they produced using elements from the rest of the body?

Comment: So you are really asking for a hypothetical testicle transplant not scrotum, the answer would still more or less be the same as given in "Is DNA replaced after organ donation?". You are not the first to ask this question, if you head over to Reddit, there's an entire thread dedicated to the subject: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/czaae/if_you_had_a_testicle_transplant_would_your_sperm/

As you can see the answer is the same..

Comment: There also is an article in The Verge: https://www.theverge.com/2018/4/26/17286728/penis-scrotum-transplant-surgery-us-veteran-johns-hopkins-testicles-ethics